# Why the index makes the query slower?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `fp_user_vcurrency_account_75` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'SPLIT_KEY',
  `vdiamond` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid_id` (`uid`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=958434 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to execute the following query:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mtime), vdiamond, id 
from fp_user_vcurrency_account_75 
where uid = 1558347 and vdiamond > 0 
order by id desc limit 20;
```

I created the index "uid_id" to accelerate the query. However, although the explain output seems all right:

```
mysql> explain select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mtime), vdiamond, id from fp_user_vcurrency_account_75 use index(uid_id) where uid = 1558347 and vdiamond > 0 order by id desc limit 20;
+----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                        | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fp_user_vcurrency_account_75 | NULL       | index | uid_id        | uid_id | 16      | NULL |   20 |    33.33 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

The query takes around 1 second. And if I don't specify the index at all, the query only takes several milliseconds. The explain output for the latter sql is as follows:

```
mysql> explain select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mtime), vdiamond, id from fp_user_vcurrency_account_75  where uid = 1558347 and vdiamond > 0 order by id desc limit 20;
+----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                        | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fp_user_vcurrency_account_75 | NULL       | index | uid_id        | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |   40 |    16.66 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Why is there such a big difference in these two sql queries? Thanks.

Comment: Can it be a cache issue? have you tried to run both queries multiple times?

Comment: 'I created the index "uid_id" to accelerate the query' - 'if I don't specify the index at all, the query only takes several milliseconds' how fast is fast enough I wonder?

Comment: @Kaddath  Yes, I tried several times. Every time the time taken is around the same.

Comment: You haven't shared the time. And try using `select sql_no_cache` so that it will not cache. And try index on `key multiple (uid,vdiamond,id)`

Comment: @James I just tried sql_no_cache, the result is still the same. The "use index(uid_id)" one takes 1.25 second; while the other one takes 0.00 second.

Comment: what about new index i have mentioned?

Comment: @James  I didn't add new index, but in the test I changed the query to "select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mtime), vdiamond, id from fp_user_vcurrency_account_75 where uid = 1558347 order by id desc limit 20".

Comment: Is `vdiamond` usually >0?  Or usually <=0?

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to optimize that type of query.

If the first 900K rows have vdiamond<=0, using `PRIMARY` will have to skip over at least that many rows.

Similarly, `uid = 1558347 and vdiamond > 0` performs poorly if there are a lot of rows with that uid, but negative vdiamond.

I would expect this to be best:  `INDEX(uid, vdiamond)`.  This will let it do all the `WHERE` work inside the index's BTree.

That index will need to fetch lots of rows, then sort them, and only then look for 20.  Note however, that both of your attempts avoided the filesort.

Sometimes the Optimizer has good statistics, sometimes it can guess right.